# Change rar icon

Tags: icons, rar, properties

How Can I Change a Specific RAR File? not all of them?
for example I have Fonts RAR and this is icon for change this RAR file[image]

Comment: What OS? What desktop environment? Or even: what application? I can imagine a file manager that displays icons according to *arbitrary* tests. Please [edit] the question and be specific.

Comment: Do you want to be able to copy/distribute the file with the custom icon, or is it just for your own convenience?

Comment: i want import in anywhere, that is a package of fonts in better say

Answer (score 1):

Icons for file associations are extension-specific. You can't set the icon based on the content of the file. You can't a file `fonts.rar` to show a font icon, and a file `documents.rar` to show a document icon. They both have a `.rar` extension.

Comment: anyway import a folder as a file? you know can change folder icon... I just want 5 files as a package but with this icon